# Group by similar attribute and join them by comma javascript - Mysql group concat like

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

I need to group the array below with similar type and separate each description with comma .

Input

```
let obj=[
  {
    "type": "Bedroom",
    "int_input": 1,
    "enum_input": 0,
    "enum_select": "Yes",
    "description": "Test"
  },
  {
    "type": "Bedroom",
    "int_input": 1,
    "enum_input": 0,
    "enum_select": "Yes",
    "description": "Test1"
  },
  {
    "type": "Bedroom",
    "int_input": 1,
    "enum_input": 0,
    "enum_select": "Yes",
    "description": "Test"
  },
  {
    "type": "Bathroom",
    "int_input": 1,
    "enum_input": 0,
    "enum_select": "Yes",
    "description": "Test"
  },
  {
    "type": "Bathroom",
    "int_input": 1,
    "enum_input": 0,
    "enum_select": "Yes",
    "description": "Test"
  },
  {
    "type": "Bathroom",
    "int_input": 1,
    "enum_input": 0,
    "enum_select": "Yes",
    "description": "Test"
  }
]
```

Output

```
let finalobj=[
  {
    "type": "Bedroom",
     "description": "Test,Test1,Test"
  },
  {
    "type": "Bathroom",
    "description": "Test,Test,Test"
  }
]
```

My attempt (I am pretty close but getting undefined in the 1st set)

```js
let obj=[
  {
    "type": "Bedroom",
    "int_input": 1,
    "enum_input": 0,
    "enum_select": "Yes",
    "description": "Test"
  },
  {
    "type": "Bedroom",
    "int_input": 1,
    "enum_input": 0,
    "enum_select": "Yes",
    "description": "Test1"
  },
  {
    "type": "Bedroom",
    "int_input": 1,
    "enum_input": 0,
    "enum_select": "Yes",
    "description": "Test"
  },
  {
    "type": "Bathroom",
    "int_input": 1,
    "enum_input": 0,
    "enum_select": "Yes",
    "description": "Test"
  },
  {
    "type": "Bathroom",
    "int_input": 1,
    "enum_input": 0,
    "enum_select": "Yes",
    "description": "Test"
  },
  {
    "type": "Bathroom",
    "int_input": 1,
    "enum_input": 0,
    "enum_select": "Yes",
    "description": "Test"
  }
]
//first take the type
let type_only=obj.map(o=>o.type);
type_only=Array.from(new Set(type_only));

let sum_obj={};
let arr=[];
//iterate types

{type_only.map((val,index) =>{
    sumobj = obj.reduce((c, v) => v.type === val ? {'description': (c.description + ','+ v.description),'type':v.type} : c, 0)
    arr.push(sumobj);
    }
    )}

console.log(arr);
console.log(type_only);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just `reduce` into an object, grouping by type, and then map back into an array of objects:

```js
const input=[
  {
    "type": "Bedroom",
    "int_input": 1,
    "enum_input": 0,
    "enum_select": "Yes",
    "description": "Test"
  },
  {
    "type": "Bedroom",
    "int_input": 1,
    "enum_input": 0,
    "enum_select": "Yes",
    "description": "Test1"
  },
  {
    "type": "Bedroom",
    "int_input": 1,
    "enum_input": 0,
    "enum_select": "Yes",
    "description": "Test"
  },
  {
    "type": "Bathroom",
    "int_input": 1,
    "enum_input": 0,
    "enum_select": "Yes",
    "description": "Test"
  },
  {
    "type": "Bathroom",
    "int_input": 1,
    "enum_input": 0,
    "enum_select": "Yes",
    "description": "Test"
  },
  {
    "type": "Bathroom",
    "int_input": 1,
    "enum_input": 0,
    "enum_select": "Yes",
    "description": "Test"
  }
];
const outputObj = input.reduce((accum, { type, description }) => {
  if (!accum[type]) accum[type] = description;
  else accum[type] += ',' + description;
  return accum;
}, {});
const output = Object.entries(outputObj).map(([ type, description]) => ({ type, description }));
console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try following

```js
let obj=[
  {
    "type": "Bedroom",
    "int_input": 1,
    "enum_input": 0,
    "enum_select": "Yes",
    "description": "Test"
  },
  {
    "type": "Bedroom",
    "int_input": 1,
    "enum_input": 0,
    "enum_select": "Yes",
    "description": "Test1"
  },
  {
    "type": "Bedroom",
    "int_input": 1,
    "enum_input": 0,
    "enum_select": "Yes",
    "description": "Test"
  },
  {
    "type": "Bathroom",
    "int_input": 1,
    "enum_input": 0,
    "enum_select": "Yes",
    "description": "Test"
  },
  {
    "type": "Bathroom",
    "int_input": 1,
    "enum_input": 0,
    "enum_select": "Yes",
    "description": "Test"
  },
  {
    "type": "Bathroom",
    "int_input": 1,
    "enum_input": 0,
    "enum_select": "Yes",
    "description": "Test"
  }
]
//first take the type
let type_only=obj.map(o=>o.type);
type_only=Array.from(new Set(type_only));

let sum_obj={};
let arr=[];
//iterate types

{type_only.map((val,index) =>{
    // c is an object, append description only and not object
    // Also, check for blank description while appending
    sumobj = obj.reduce((c, v) => v.type === val ? {'description': (c.description ? c.description + ','+ v.description : v.description),'type':v.type} : c, 0)
    arr.push(sumobj);
    }
    )}

console.log(arr);
console.log(type_only);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use reduce, build a base object if it doesn't exist on the accumulator, and add the current description. Use [`Object.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) to convert back to array:

```js
const obj = [{"type":"Bedroom","int_input":1,"enum_input":0,"enum_select":"Yes","description":"Test"},{"type":"Bedroom","int_input":1,"enum_input":0,"enum_select":"Yes","description":"Test1"},{"type":"Bedroom","int_input":1,"enum_input":0,"enum_select":"Yes","description":"Test"},{"type":"Bathroom","int_input":1,"enum_input":0,"enum_select":"Yes","description":"Test"},{"type":"Bathroom","int_input":1,"enum_input":0,"enum_select":"Yes","description":"Test"},{"type":"Bathroom","int_input":1,"enum_input":0,"enum_select":"Yes","description":"Test"}];

const result = Object.values(obj.reduce((r, { type, description }) => {
  r[type] = r[type] || { type, description: '' };
  
  r[type].description += `${r[type].description ? ' ,' : ''}${description}`;
  
  return r;
}, Object.create(null)));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array#reduce` with `Map`.

```js
let arr = [ { "type": "Bedroom", "int_input": 1, "enum_input": 0, "enum_select": "Yes", "description": "Test" }, { "type": "Bedroom", "int_input": 1, "enum_input": 0, "enum_select": "Yes", "description": "Test1" }, { "type": "Bedroom","int_input": 1, "enum_input": 0, "enum_select": "Yes", "description": "Test" }, { "type": "Bathroom", "int_input": 1, "enum_input": 0, "enum_select": "Yes", "description": "Test" }, { "type": "Bathroom", "int_input": 1, "enum_input": 0, "enum_select":"Yes", "description": "Test" }, { "type": "Bathroom", "int_input": 1, "enum_input": 0, "enum_select": "Yes", "description": "Test" } ],
    result = [...arr.reduce((map,{type, description}) => {
      map.has(type) ? map.get(type).description += ', ' + description : map.set(type, {type, description});
      return map;
    },new Map).values()];
console.log(result);
```